# Run console games on PC

Tags: windows, game, emulator

Recently, i saw that Ubisoft will be releasing Assassin’s Creed 5 Unity only for consoles. It upset me a lot since I only have a PC and it the best platform for gaming. Is there a way to run out anyway, like wine does for games on Linux?

Comment: There are emulators for several consoles out there, but they rarely work well with the latest consoles. Examples: [Dolphin (Wii emulator)](http://www.dolphin-emulator.com/), [PCSX2 (Playstation 2)](http://pcsx2.net/) , zsnes (SuperNintendo) etc

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassin%27s_Creed_Unity : "it would also see a release on Windows"

Comment: The article dates back from July. From [a French site](http://www.jeuxvideo.com/news/2014/00073296-assassin-s-creed-unity-un-nouveau-cycle-pour-le-present.htm#news), they say approximately that unity n will be released exclusively for last generation consoles.

Comment: I'm fairly certain they just meant that Unity won't be released for 360 or PS3. As for your question: To properly emulate (meaning "accurately" and "with acceptable speed") a machine, you need a host that is at least 20 times as powerful as the client. Even the most powerful PCs of 2013 have difficulties emulating PS2/Xbox/NGC/Wii games at full speed. Now imagine emulating the PS3/360, let alone their successors.